# Why does my iPhone stop playing Apple Music through my headphones in car?

Tags: audio, iphone, headphones, car-integration

My iPhone plays music through any headphones perfectly. However, when I'm in a car and the car accelerates to a certain speed, at first I hear clicks every two to three seconds and then if the car goes faster the music stops, but the clicks get louder that I have to take it off.

Why does this happen? What are the causes? Anyway to fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify how you're connecting your iPhone to the car? And, while in the car, are you still using headphones to listen to the music, or are you talking about the audio coming through your car's speakers?

Comment: @Monomeeth  actually I'm not connecting the phone to the car just the Iphone and the headphones, and yes it only happens with music the calls are normal .

Comment: What app do you use to play music?

Comment: Does it only happen in the one car? Or does it happen regardless of which car you're in?

Comment: @rwzdoorn  Apple Music, anghami

Comment: @Monomeeth  any car actually but I think when they  reache the same speed

Comment: Okay, have you tested whether the same thing happens with a different pair of headphones?

Comment: @Monomeeth actually no but I'll borrow one from my friend and see , I'll give update .

Comment: That'd be great. Troubleshooting is a process of elimination, so we need to eliminate the simplest possibilities first.